# Get multiple values from DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**The Coding Challenge**

2 Teams play against each other, each team has 15 positions, and 15 players. Each squad of a team contains 45 players *but only 15 players can start in their respective positions when the match start*. Thus with a squad of 45 players it allows the coach the option of choosing 1 player for a position out of a possible 3 choices.

**What I must do**

I have a table of 15 different teams with all their squad members and positions. When a user selects a team from a dropdown, it displays the different positions and the players eligible for selection in that position for that specific team through a dropdown menu, as you can see in the image below:
[image]

**The Drop Down Lets The user Select 1 of 15 different Teams After The User Clicks View The Positions And Players Eligible For Selection For That Specific Position Gets Displayed As You Can See In The Next Image  **

[image]

*Now The User Can Select His Team As Desired. As you Can See From The Image Above*

**The Problem Im Having**

Displaying squad members and different selection options is easy enough, however there are 2 teams playing against each other and the user must select the teams for not just one team but BOTH teams.
Thus I need to have the user select two teams from the teams drop down menu (image1) and then display team selection for team2 like it did for team1 (see image2) I've been trying to solve this for a number of hours now with no luck

My code Follows

```
<form name="team_select" method="post" >
    Team :<select id="team1" name="team1_select[]" class="basic">
        <optgroup label="New Zealand teams">
            <option value="Crusaders">Crusaders</option>
            <option value="Blues">Blues</option>
            <option value="Highlanders">Highlanders</option>
            <option value="Hurricanes">Hurricanes</option>
            <option value="Chiefs">Chiefs</option>
        </optgroup>  
        <optgroup label="Australian teams">
            <option value="Brumbies">Brumbies</option>
            <option value="Reds">Reds</option>
            <option value="Rebels">Rebels</option>
            <option value="Waratahs">Waratahs</option>
            <option value="WesternForce">Western Force</option>
        </optgroup>   
        <optgroup label="South African teams">
            <option value="Stormers">Stormers</option>
            <option value="Sharks">Sharks</option>
            <option value="Bulls">Bulls</option>
            <option value="Cheetahs">Cheetahs</option>
            <option value="Lions">Lions</option>
            <option value="Kings">*Kings*</option>
        </optgroup>   
    </select>


    <input type="submit" value="View" id="view" name="select" onclick="" />    
</form>
```

```
<?PHP

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

//This code gets executed after form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['select']))
{
    foreach($_REQUEST["team1_select"] as $t1select)
    {
        $t1select = $t1select;
        echo $t1select;
    }//end foreach
    //assign each position to variable position
    $position = array("prop", "hooker", "prop", "lock", "lock", "flank", "flank", "no8", "scrumhalf", "flyhalf", "center", "center", "wing", "wing", "fullback");
    //for loop to loop through the number of positions in the team, which will be used to query DB 
    $size = sizeof($position);
    for($i=0; $i< $size; $i++){

        //Query For Props
        $sqlprops = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `allsquads` WHERE `Team` ='$t1select' && `Position` = '$position[$i]'") or die(mysql_error());
        echo'<form name="teamselect" method="post">';

        echo '<br>';
        echo $position[$i];
        echo'<select name="team[]">';

        //extract results
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlprops))
        {
            //display various props names to select

            echo '<option value="'.$row['Rating'].'">'.$row['Player'].'</option>'; 
        }//end while

        echo'</select>';

    }//end for loop
}//end isset
?>
```

If anyone can offer a bit of help or advice it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

(P.S I know my code is vulnerable to sql injections and I should rather use PDO statements but Im still learning and our lecturer has advised us to use the deprecated functions for now)

Comment: It sounds a bit like rugby. Is it fantasy rugby?

Comment: Let's say there are 50 teams, each with 45 players - so 2250 players. This is a trivial amount, and could I suspect easily be managed entirely within php/javascript, without any additional hit on the database. Just hide or show <li> items depending upon the options selected. Anyway, just my 2c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build this I would have two sets of forms, populated by one query (splitting out the data) or two separate queries.  I would also use javascript to validate that the same player isn't put in multiple positions (since I assume one person can't be in multiple positions).

Strawberry is probably correct that this could easily be maintained without a database, but a database will make scaling it much easier (as well as modifications).